# Generate a duplicate of an item upon dragging, ensuring that it's the clone being moved, not the original item, using Android Kotlin (XML)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm developing a drag-and-drop application that allows users to move objects within the main interface. The challenge I'm facing involves generating unlimited duplicates of a particular item view, enabling endless dragging capabilities for that item.

These items are dynamically generated and organized in a grid layout. I aim to enable the dragging of these item copies to a custom-made calendar within the application. Additionally, it's crucial that the original item stays intact in its original position.

the items creation:

```
private fun setupActivitiesGridLayout(items: List<CalendarItem>) {
        val gridLayout = GridLayout(context).apply {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            ).apply {
                topToTop = binding.daysSlots.id

            }
            orientation = GridLayout.VERTICAL
        }
        binding.testSectionCalendar.addView(gridLayout)
        addCalendarActivityItems(items, gridLayout)
    }

    // creates the items that need to be dragged to the calendar
    private fun addCalendarActivityItems(items: List<CalendarItem>, gridLayout: GridLayout) {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            val activityView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.calendar_activity_item, binding.testSectionCalendar, false)
            activityView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.item).setImageResource(item.imageResId)

            val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ).apply {
                startToStart = binding.daysSlots.id
                endToEnd = binding.activities.id
                topToTop = binding.daysSlots.id
                setMargins(30, if (index == 0) 100 else 20, 30, 10)
            }

            activityView.layoutParams = layoutParams
            gridLayout.addView(activityView)

        }
    }
```

the xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".feature.calendar_question.CalendarFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/calendar"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/test_section_calendar"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <!-- Horizontal Guideline to center vertically -->
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/days_slots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.125"/>

            <!-- Vertical Guideline to divide the layout into two equal parts -->
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/activities"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/time_slots"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:rowCount="8"
                android:columnCount="5"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_selector"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activities"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/days">


            </GridLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/times"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_selector"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/activities"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/days_slots">


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/days"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_selector"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/days_slots"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activities"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/next_Btn"
            style="@style/primaryButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/next_button_hitbear" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Am I missing something in the example above?